# How to validate XPath expression in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, xpath

Given a xpath expression string, is it possible to validate its syntax in NodeJS?

Some things to note:

- Assume what you have will only be a xpath expression as a string. Therefore there is no document to evaluate the xpath against as a way to test if the expression is possibly syntactically valid.
- As this validation will be in the NodeJS environment you won't have access to the `Document` interface. Therefore `createExpression` and `evaluate` can't be used.

Comment: do you want to write it on your own or you are searching for a tool? Check [the XPath standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)

Comment: @smnbbrv: I'm looking for a method/tool that already does this. But if one doesn't exist then I might consider creating my own.

Comment: There is https://www.npmjs.com/package/xpath, I don't really see why installing a module that does exactly what you need would be off-limits.

Comment: @Tomalak: I might be wrong, but as far as I know the "xpath" npm package **evaluates** xpaths. This is differing from what I'd like to do which is **validate** the xpath. I realize that if an xpath returns results successfully then the xpath is valid, however an xpath can return `null` even if the syntax is valid (because there are no matching nodes). Also, in the context where I will be validating xpaths there will not be a document to evaluate xpaths against.

Comment: Academical difference. Evaluating an XPath expression involves parsing it. Rolling your own XPath parser is not recommended when mature and tested XPath implementations are readily available. You can always evaluate it against an empty document if you want to check syntax validity only.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yes, I agree that creating a custom parser is not recommended – let alone worth the time and effort required to do it – which is why it's a last resort should I not find a method/tool that will solve the problem satisfactorily. As for the difference, it's a big enough difference in this case to differentiate them. I've considered evaluating against an empty/minimal document although it's not the cleanest solution available so that's in the list of back-up plans. Thanks for suggesting.